# painting a line via canvas over a imageview while fragment is created

Tags: canvas, bitmap, imageview, fragment

Right now i am trying to solve an issue while programming a small app with Android Studio.

I have a Main Activity which is used for switching between different Fragments in my Code . Now i Need to load a new Fragment if the orientation of my device is getting switched (for example from Portrait to landscape). I am doing this with the method

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

and everything seems to be fine at this Point.

In my first Fragment i have a imageview which will be "overdrawn" with a single canvas line. Because of the new orientation fragment needs to have the same sized imageview (included with the XML_layout file) with the same line, i am saving the coordinates, getting them out of my old Fragment class before switching to the new one, and trying to draw the new imageview again with that line. The canvas line method just calculates the coordinates via an passed by angle (first Attribute).
Additionaly i am displaying the value of the coordinates in a editText field.

Now my issue is, that after rotating the device, i will see the coordinates in my editText field but i cant draw my ImageView in the new Fragment because of i am triggering that Event with a TextWatcher / afterTextChanged

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          drawLineOne(50, Color.Green, MyImVi);  
        }
    });
```

and that Textwatcher lies in the

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

of my new Fragment.

The idea by that Textwatcher is to redraw the line everytime after a new angle is included to that editText.

Now i've tried to draw that line also if the orientation has changed and there are processible data for my new angle (the whole idea is to have a comparison line which i want to have in both imageviews, landscapemode and portraitmode).

But if i am trying to Trigger my drawLineOne method at another place like onViewCreated i am getting in error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

This happens while creating the Bitmap file for my Canvas object:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(MyImVi.getWidth(), MyImVi.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Is there any way to call or create a function which will be triggered after the orientation has been changed and the new Fragment is visible in my activity? I guess thats the main issue why it occurs, ive already tried to call my drawLineOne in:

- onStart()
- onResume()
- onActivityCreated()
- onViewCreated() in the Head (before assigning the Textwatcher)
  also like that

  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser){
      super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
      if(isVisibleToUser){
          if(interimValueAzimut != null) {
              drawLineOne(50,Color.GREEN, imageViewAzimut_ls);
          }
      }
  }

Or is there a much easier way to draw that line after Rotation? maybe with another method with my TextWatcher?

I just got started with Java and getting better with it but always getting stuck at issues like this so please be gentle :)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Alright i've managed to solve my Problem by checking more stackoverflow Q&A threads.
I just took an TreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
        }
    });
```

Anyways, solved :)